# Serialize any type of list to XML?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, xml-serialization

I have 4 entity class . A,B,C,D.It has different properties like ID,Address and even complex type.I want to Write a common Method where i can pass any list and it will convert to XML. Let say

```
public string GetAnyListtoXML(Any type of list)
        {
            string myXML=string.Empty;

return myXML;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This method allow you to serialize whatever you want.
Your entity class should have parameterless constructor.

This link may be helpful to control serialization: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

```
    public string ObjectToXml<T>(T obj)
    {
        var stream = new StringWriter();

        string xmlDoc = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (T));
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(stream, obj);
            xmlDoc = stream.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Błąd pliku xml: " + ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            stream.Close();
        }
        return xmlDoc;
    }



    public static T XmlToObject<T>(string xmlDoc)
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        byte[] xmlObject = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(xmlDoc);

        stream.Write(xmlObject, 0, xmlObject.Length);
        stream.Position = 0;
        T message;

        var ss = new XmlSerializer(typeof (T));
        try
        {
            message = (T) ss.Deserialize(stream);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            message = default(T);
        }
        finally
        {
            stream.Close();
        }
        return message;
    }
```

If you want to this method take only list, you can use it:

```
    public string ObjectToXml<T>(List<T> obj)
    {
        var stream = new StringWriter();

        string xmlDoc = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (List<T>));
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(stream, obj);
            xmlDoc = stream.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Błąd pliku xml: " + ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            stream.Close();
        }
        return xmlDoc;
    }
```